# Create a multivariate function from a set of points

Tags: multivariable-calculus, graphing-functions, multivariate-polynomial

I am looking to construct a graph for illustrative purposes. I have a few restrictions that come from visualizing how the graph should look, in the form of $f(x,y) = z$.

- $f(\infty,\infty) = \infty$
- $0 < f(\infty,0) < \infty$
- $f(0,\infty) = f(\infty,0)$
- $f(0,0) = 0$
- $f(-\infty,-\infty) = -\infty$
- $f(\infty,-\infty) =  -|f(\infty,0)|$

And for illustrative reasons, the negative-$x$ does not matter.

How would one go about approaching this?